# File permissions get overwritten when editing file remotely in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions, remote-access

I use Ubuntu for development (12.10 currently). I usually work on files by mounting remote resource in nautilus by SSH. Files on the remote server are owned by different user and my user account is attached to that user's group so I can have full access. The problem I'm experiencing is that every time I edit a file and save it I become the owner of that file. This causes other users not being able to work on those file anymore. It seems like using FTP client like Filezilla solves the problem (ownership does not change) but I don't want to switch back using FTP client. 
I did a bit of research online and run across couple posts where people were heaving the same issue but the problem was not solved.

Comment: Does your choice of editor impact on this behaviour?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. I'm using Sublime but tried others and same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are editing files on a remote server. Does it matter if other users have access to you user folder and files on that server? Probably not.

Say you are user `marcin`, with group name `marcin`, then you could add other users to group `marcin`. Then another user (john) edits a file and ownership changes to `john:john`. So you need to add all users to group `john`. Do this for all users that should have access to these files.

Not a beautiful solution, but I can't think of a better one.